# mono - winforms not working properly with f#

Tags: winforms, f#, mono, monodevelop

I have successfully installed MonoDevelop with the F# bindings (under Linux Arch).

If I try a simple HelloWorld with winforms, I get this strange behavior: the program compiles and builds successfully, but a moment after the window is loaded it just closes itself and the program returns with no error messages.

I checked the logs and it seems no error is thrown (except from the one discussed here: [GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID XXX was not found when attempting to remove it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199699/glib-critical-source-id-xxx-was-not-found-when-attempting-to-remove-it), which anyway seems unrelated).

The code for the program:

```
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let form = new Form(TopMost = true, Text = "Hello World")
    form.Show()
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

If I try to run it through the interactive console, the window is sort of freezed: I can move it around, but I can't close it (have to shut down monodevelop in order to do so).

I also tried to compile it via terminal, using:

```
fsharpc Program.fs -pkg:dotnet.dll
mono Program.exe
```

but it behaves the same way as if I was running through MonoDevelop (window opens then shuts down). 
Other than that F# seems to work fine, I can run console programs without any problem.

I also tried to run a simple HelloWorld program with C# in MonoDevelop, and it just works fine.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

You need to start the forms event loop with something like

```
Application.Run(new Form())
```

Comment: Tried a moment ago, it worked just fine :) Thank you! I read it was not advisable to use Application.Run() in favor of form.Show(), but this seems to be definitely not the case. Oh well.